# iOS adaptive view; adaptive constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, constraints

What I'm trying to achieve is an adaptive view for iPhones based on a 4.7" screen in the layouts.

Now achieving this is proving difficult, this is also my first experience with constraints.

I don't wish to use free-form as it seems so foreign to me and my intented targets are not iPads.

Also, the current project i'm on won't allow me to switch to freeform viewcontroller sizes for some reason.

[image: iPhone 4 based on 4.7" layout without constraints]
[image: iPhone 4 based on 4.7" with constraints top/bottom]
[image: iPhone 6 based on 4.7" with constraints]

first is iphone 4 without constraints based on 4.7" layout
second is iphone 4 with constraints based on 4.7" layout
third is what the iphone 6 layout appears as.

I want to keep the same general distance, but shrink everything to match on a smaller screen size ideally. (distance wise, not button/text size etc)

so as you can see I'm achieving a result regardless, however my top label is measured from the top and the buttons are from the bottom, anything else I try appears to push the rest of the buttons out of view.

However, how can I programatically achieve this

```
if (iphone screen is 4.7") {
    bottom constraint is 95px.height;
} else
if (iphone screen is 4.0") {    
    bottom constraint is 50px.height;
} else
if (iphone screen is 3.5") {
    bottom constraint is 10px.height;
}
```

This is how I plan to make my application adaptive, but I need the constraints to be adaptive too. If I'm approaching this wrong, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you might approach this.  One way is to use both the multiplier and constant of the constraint to give you the correct spacing for those screen sizes. If you solve for these two equations,

480x + y = 470 (480 - your wanted bottom constraint of 10) and

667x + y = 572 (667 - your wanted bottom constraint of 95)

you get a values of 0.5455 for x and 208.2 for y. If you plug those into your other equation (568x + y = 518) it works out quite close too. So for that bottom constraint, you want to have

button bottom = superview bottom * 0.5455 + 208.2

You can make this in IB by adding a bottom constraint to your bottom button (or label) and editing it to change the multiplier and constant values. You could do the same with your top view to make it proportional to the screen size, but beware that you actually need to make the constraint to the bottom of the super view because the value of superview.top is 0, so using a multiplier will do you no good. To space all the views evenly in between, the best way is to use spacer views (if you search "space views evenly" on SO, you'll find some answers that explain that).

Another way to do this might be to use a table view instead of individual labels and buttons. The advantage of this approach is that the views (cells in this case) will be automatically spaced evenly (based on the row height). You could still give the table view constraints to the top and bottom like I outlined above, or just center it vertically, and make it's height proportional to the superview's height. I think this is probably the better, and certainly easier approach. If you make the table view non-scrolling, and have no cell separators, it will look just like the other approach.